# Forcing color profile to sRGB in Chrome 100

Tags: google-chrome, color-profiles

The recent Chrome 100 update looks to have removed the #force-color-profile flag.

How can I make Chrome 100 always use the sRGB color profile?

I searched flags for "color" and "profile" but didn't see any similar setting.

Comment: You mean force for untagged or force all? I had previously set chrome to force for untagged & tested on build 98 then 100 & see no changes in behaviour using the [Greg Benz test page]{https://gregbenzphotography.com/photography-tips/how-to-setup-proper-color-management-in-a-web-browser}. I have Chrome open next to Safari & the only difference I see is that even build 100 cannot yet see the CSS in P3 images at all [Safari can]. I have a fully colour-managed workflow. I found #forced-colors though I'm not seeing any behaviour change with that enabled. Colours are still rendering correctly.

Comment: @Tetsujin Untagged is my main target; I haven't actually tested yet so that's good to know; perhaps they made it less aggressive. I also have a fully managed workflow and Chrome < 100 always caused problems with inappropriate correction. I'll see how it goes with the new version. I also found #forced-colors but my limited understanding is that it is for forcing user-defined palettes for accessibility reasons or something, don't quote me on that though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome 100 has retired the flag of `#force-color-profile`.

Below are two temporary methods, to be used as long as they keep on working:

- Launch Chrome adding the following switch to the target field:
  `--force-color-profile=srgb`
- Re-enable old flags in `chrome://flags/` by enabling:

  - Temporarily unexpire M98 flags (`#temporary-unexpire-flags-m98`)
  - Temporarily unexpire M99 flags (`#temporary-unexpire-flags-m99`)

  This will resuscitate `#force-color-profile`.

Comment: I wonder if Chrome changed color management strategies to be more cooperative, prompting them to remove the flag. I'll check through the release notes if I have time later and stick any info I find here. However, having just re-enabled forced sRGB via the expired flags, after relaunching Chrome I immediately noticed a difference in the blue buttons on the flags page, and the blues and greens here.

Comment: Are you on Mac or Win? I only tested this on Mac. I had that test page side by side in Safari & Chrome, & saw nothing I didn't expect; same on both.

Comment: @Tetsujin Windows 10. Also, to be clearer: The differences I noticed in v100 are the same differences that appear in previous versions; so it wasn't completely unexpected. I.e. I was trying to say that it didn't look to me like v100 improved anything under the hood (otherwise I'd have expected no color changes), not that I was surprised by the changes. I've got a calibrated display with X-Rite applying correction globally, and Chrome doesn't seem to interact well with it (I was hoping v100 improved that but alas). I would've thought that removing the flag implied that an improvement was made.